# making ajax button with django-secretballot and intercooler.js

Tags: django, ajax

I'm making a vote up button using django-secretballot and django-likes and i want to use intercooler.js to make the ajax call and don't reload the whole page.

The problem is when i click on the vote button the element contain the ( vote_total ) disappear and nothing happen but if i reload the page the vote happen

image 1 : the button without click

image 2 : the button after i click

image 3 : the button after i reload the page

[image: the button without click] [image]
[image]

this is "likes.html" template on django-likes app

```
{% load i18n %}
{% load static %}

{% if import_js %}
   <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'likes/includes/likes.js' %}"></script>
   <script src="{% static 'intercoolerjs/js/jquery.js' %}"></script>
   <script src="{% static 'intercoolerjs/js/intercooler.min.js' %}"></script>
{% endif %}

{% if likes_enabled %}
  {% if can_vote %}
    <a class="liker vote rounded" ic-get-from="{% url 'like' content_type content_obj.id 1 %}" ic-target="#wrapper" ic-select-from-response="#wrapper" rel="nofollow">
        <svg width="10" height="9" viewBox="0 0 9 8" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="upvoteIcon_f942d"><path d="M9 8H0l4.5-8L9 8z" fill-rule="evenodd"></path></svg>
        <span id="wrapper" class="number" style="display: inline-block">
            <div id="target">
                {{content_obj.vote_total }}
            </div>
        </span>
    </a>
  {% else %}
    <a class="vote liked rounded">
        <svg width="10" height="9" viewBox="0 0 9 8" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="upvoteIcon_f942d"><path d="M9 8H0l4.5-8L9 8z" fill-rule="evenodd"></path></svg>
        <span class="number">
            {{content_obj.vote_total }}
        </span>
    </a>
  {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

**Note :** if there is noway to make intercooler.js working with django-secretballot and django-likes can you please give me ajax code to make the button don't reload the whole page thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was on the `id` of the `span`; it must be unique so I solve it like this

```
 <a class="liker vote rounded" ic-get-from="{% url 'like' content_type content_obj.id 1 %}" ic-src="{% url 'like' content_type content_obj.id 1 %}" ic-target="#wrapper-{{  content_obj.id }}" ic-select-from-response="span" rel="nofollow">

        <span id="wrapper-{{  content_obj.id }}" class="number" style="display: inline-block">
             {{content_obj.vote_total }}
        </span>
    </a>
```